Adding items to cart
In my group project, I am creating an "add to cart" function for a website. How can I add an "add to cart" button that will add item to cart and redirects user to the cart page? Within the cart page, I need the items that have been added to show. As of now, I have created the button, but it doesn't redirects the user to cart page. It stays on the product page.
//Cart Controller
class CartController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @cart = Prebuilt.all
    render :index
  end

  def show
    @cart = current_cart
   end

  def add_to_cart
    current_cart.add_item(params[:prebuilt_id])
  end

end

//Cart Model
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items

  def add_item(prebuilt_id)
    item = items.where('prebuilt_id', prebuilt_id.first)
    save
  end

end

//Item Model
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart
end

//Routes
# root to: redirect('/cart')

  get 'cart', to: 'cart#index', as: 'cart';

  post '/add_to_cart/:prebuilt_id' => 'cart#add_to_cart', :as => 'add_to_cart'

  get 'checkout', to: 'pages#checkout', as: 'checkout';

  get 'confirm', to: 'pages#confirm', as: 'confirm';

// Seeds.rb
prebuilt1 = Prebuilt.create!(
  name: "Alfred's Artistic Jet",
  description: "Designed by Alfred",
  manufacturer: "Boeing",
  color: "Mixed",
  size: "Large",
  price: 2999999
)

prebuilt2 = Prebuilt.create!(
  name: "Brittany's Barbie Jet",
  description: "Designed by Brittany",
  manufacturer: "Boeing",
  color: "Pink",
  size: "Large",
  price: 4499999
)

prebuilt3 = Prebuilt.create!(
  name: "Peter's Prehistoric Jet",
  description: "Designed by Peter",
  manufacturer: "Airbus",
  color: "Blue",
  size: "Small",
  price: 7999999
)

prebuilt4 = Prebuilt.create!(
  name: "Tianna's Tractor-Themed Jet",
  description: "Designed by Tianna",
  manufacturer: "Airbus",
  color: "Mixed",
  size: "Large",
  price: 1999999
)

// Product Page
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">

  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Manufacturer</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @prebuilts.each do |prebuilt| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= prebuilt.name %></td>
        <td><%= prebuilt.description %></td>
        <td><%= prebuilt.description %></td>
        <td><%= prebuilt.manufacturer %></td>
        <td><%= prebuilt.color %></td>
        <td><%= prebuilt.size %></td>
        <td><%= prebuilt.price %></td>
        <td class="text-nowrap">
          <%= link_to 'show', prebuilt_path(prebuilt), class: 'btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary' %>
          <td><%= button_to "add to cart", cart_path(:prebuilt_id => prebuilt), method: :post %></td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>

</table>

// Cart Page
<table id="line_items">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th class="price">Unit Price</th>
    <th class="price">Full Price</th>
  </tr>

  <% for item in @cart %>
    <tr class="<%= cycle :odd, :even %>
       <td><%=h item.name %></td>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>


There is no question here. It is not understandable, what specific problem you need to resolve. Text looks like task rather than question with description of the issue

Question has been edited

"but it doesn't redirects the user to cart page" - you have no redirects in your controller, you've already got an answer about that. use add_to_cart_path for your button.

class CartController < ApplicationController
  def add_to_cart
    current_cart.add_item(params[:prebuilt_id])
    redirect_to cart_path(current_cart.id)
  end
end

Item should probably belongs to Prebuild too
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :prebuild
end

And adding item is like searching existing one and updating it or creating new
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items

  def add_item(prebuilt_id)
    item = items.find_by(prebuilt_id: prebuilt_id)
    if item
      item.update(count: item.count + 1)
    else
      items.create(prebuilt_id: prebuilt_id, count: 1)
    end
  end
end

Or if you don't have counts and each position can be just 1
  def add_item(prebuilt_id)
    items.find_or_create_by(prebuilt_id: prebuilt_id)
  end


When I click the "add to cart" button that I've created, it doesn't direct me to the cart page with the item added. Am I missing something?

in the topic description you said it adds the item and directs the user to the cart page, so controller adds item and redirects to cart path, for rendering items in the cart - you need modify view


How can I add an "add to cart" button that will add item to cart and redirects user to the cart page?

Firstly you need to fix your button_to such way:
<% @prebuilts.each do |prebuilt| %>
  <%= button_to "add to cart", add_to_cart_path(prebuilt_id: prebuilt.id) %>
<% end %>

Action path for this form should be add_to_cart_path, not cart_path
method: :post is default, don't need to specify it
You also need to change controller action
def add_to_cart
  current_cart.add_item(params[:prebuilt_id])
  redirect_to cart_path
end

Due to your routes and URL helpers this way you will add item and redirect to cart. But you need somehow implement Cart#add_item method, but it's impossible to answer how to do it because it is unknown how cart, item and prebuilt are associated with each other
